# How can I get all gameobjects to check what gameobjects have colliders and what colliders and what gameobjects dont have colliders at all?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Collider> allColliders = new List<Collider>();

    private List<GameObject> allObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();

        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
        {
            foreach (Collider collider in go.transform.GetComponents<Collider>())
            {
                allColliders.Add(collider);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

In the end I want to have two lists maybe to write them to a text file for example output format:

Wall1 --  BoxCollider,CapsuleCollider

Door22 -- No Colliders

Door10 -- BoxCollider

Something like this. The goal is to find what gameobjects have colliders what colliders and what gameobjects don't have colliders at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to get all of the collider on the object and then check the length of the returned array, if it's 0 then there are no colliders otherwise there are:

```cs
void Start()
{
    allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();

    foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
    {
        var colliders = go.transform.GetComponents<Collider>();

        int length = colliders.Length;

        if (length == 0)
        {  
            Debug.Log(string.Format("{0} - No Colliders", go.name));
        }
        else
        {
            //composes a list of the colliders types, this will print what you want e.g. "Wall1 - BoxCollider, MeshCollider"

            string colliderTypes = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                colliderTypes = string.Format("{0}{1}", colliderTypes, colliders[i].GetType().Name);

                if (i != (length - 1))
                {
                    colliderTypes = string.Format("{0}, ", colliderTypes);
                }
            }
            Debug.Log(string.Format("{0} - {1}", go.name, colliderTypes));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Collider` class is the base of 3D colliders, if you will also need to check for 2D ones then get all `Collider2D` components and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetType` to compare the colliders to each subclass of collider:

```
foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
{
    print (go + " has:");
    foreach (Collider collider in go.transform.GetComponents<Collider>())
    {
        if(collider.GetType() == typeof(MeshCollider)) print("mesh");
        else if(collider.GetType() == typeof(BoxCollider)) print("box");
        else if(collider.GetType() == typeof(CapsuleCollider)) print("capsule");
        else if(collider.GetType() == typeof(SphereCollider)) print("sphere");
        else print("other");
    }
}
```

The question is vague about exactly what you'd like to do after identifying the type of collider, so it's just printing here.

Instead of printing, you could add a new key to a dictionary with an empty list, and then append to that list in the inner foreach.